# how does missing data work in cloudwatch alarm?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

a cloudwatch alarm for api gateway endpoint. based on documentation, i have created template below and way i read it, is if there is 5xx error, which will be greater than '0' threshold, this should trigger. i'm not sure about the "TreatMissingData" attribute below, what data does this refer too? also not sure about the "EvaluationPeriods" attribute as well? can someone explain on it?

```
loudAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    Namespace: AWS/ApiGateay
    MetricName: 5XXError
    Period: '60'
    EvaluationPeriods: '1'
    Threshold: 0
    Statistic: Sum
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
    TreatMissingData: ?????????
    AlarmActions:
      ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TreatMissingData**
is a parameter how to do when the data is missing.

Values are:

- breaching: missing data is treated as breaching threshold
- notBreaching: treated as within threshold
- ignore: missing data is ignored
- missing: ignored, if all of data missing in the period range, alarm `INSUFFICIENT_DATA`

if not specified, `missing` is used.

**EvaluationPeriods** is a parameter how many times the threshold has to be breached for alarm.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

Comment: thanks. when we say data , which data are we talking about

Comment: The "data" in "MissingData"  is metric data in cloudwatch.

Comment: thanks again. I guess it should be safe to ignore then. I just wanted to make sure that it won't trigger the alarm

Comment: @shimo- sorry I know the question is closed, i set up the alarm and i getting notifications with following in the email. It has 3 things listed under and i'm not sure about the 3rd one below i.e. INSUFFICIENT_DATA. is the alarm triggering because of the insufficient data?  -  state change actions : - ok - Alamrm [arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:384783748:apigatewayerror] - INSUFFICIENT_DATA:

Comment: INSUFFICIENT_DATA means alarm is ignored because data is insufficient.

Comment: can this be done when calculating tm99 as well? can we ignore missing data when we graph tm99.