# How to implement AWS RDS Read/Write Latency Cloudwatch alarms using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to set new AWS RDS Read/Write Latency Cloudwatch alarms using Terraform. I have googled a alot to find some examples for the same but i didn't find any.

what i have wrote in the terraform main.tf. Is this code snippet correct or not?

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "postgres_write_latency" {
  count               = length(var.db_instance_identifier)
  alarm_name          = "rds-postgres-write-latency-canada"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "WriteLatency"
  namespace           = "AWS/RDS"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "2"
  treat_missing_data  = "breaching"

  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier    = element(var.db_instance_identifier, count.index)
  }

  alarm_description = "Write IOPS for rds postgres in Canada ${terraform.workspace}"
  alarm_actions     = [var.sns_topic] 
  ok_actions        = [var.sns_topic]
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "postgres_read_latency" {
  count               = length(var.db_instance_identifier)
  alarm_name          = "rds-postgres-read-latency-canada"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "ReadLatency"
  namespace           = "AWS/RDS"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "0.030"
  treat_missing_data  = "breaching"

  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier    = element(var.db_instance_identifier, count.index)
  }

  alarm_description = "Read IOPS for rds postgres in Canada ${terraform.workspace}"
  alarm_actions     = [var.sns_topic] 
  ok_actions        = [var.sns_topic]
}
```

I have implemented this code but it start spamming the slack channel due to INSUFFICIENT_DATA.

I need a working terraform code for AWS RDS Read/Write Latency Cloudwatch alarms.

Comment: The code looks correct (as long as `var.db_instance_identifier` contains a valid DB identifier). I would start by logging into the AWS web console and looking at the alarm in CloudWatch, and compare it to the actual metric in CloudWatch you are trying to track, and see if you can spot what the issue is.

Comment: Your'e probably missing a parameter in the dimensions{} block. Make sure it exactly matches the metric in Cloudwatch metrics

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `treat_missing_data  = "breaching"`. What this does is tell cloudwatch that if it has missing data the threshold should be considered breached. The available options and their explanations can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69353795